# Custom Attribute is executed at compile time

Tags: c#, aop, custom-attributes

I'm trying to create a custom attribute that will work in a sort-of AOP way (I don't have access to postsharp, unfortunately and I'm not very familiar with Unity). It has AttributeUsage.Method and in its constructor it configures some parts of the test environment (pulls some info out of app.config and calls some exes that config the environment).

It works, except that right now, when I build the solution, the attribute is executed - which is undesireable.

Is there a way to create a custom attribute that isn't executed at compile time?

edit> I guess an example usage might help:

```
public void Scenario1Tests
{
    [Test]
    [Environment(Environments.A)]
    public void Scenario1TestA()
    {
        Assert.Something();
    }

    [Test]
    [Environment(Environments.Any)]
    public void Scenario1TestB()
    {
        Assert.SomethingElse();
    }
}

// Most tests will be written environment independent, some must not
public enum Environments
{
    A, 
    B, 
    Any
};

[AtrributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public void Environment : Attribute
{
    public Environment(Environments env)
    {
        // lots of test can have this attribute, requirement is 
        // that it is only configured once as it is a lengthy configuration
        if (this.EnvironmentIsAlreadyConfigured())
            return;

        this.GetSettingsFromAppConfig();
        Process.Start(/* ... */); // can take 20 mins+
    }        

    public Environment()
        : this(Environments.Any)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the attribute's constructor runs *during compile*? If it does, then I don't know why Visual Studio bothers with nagging me about potentially hostile code from custom build steps...

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: pretty sure. I don't have any build events, the exes that it calls are the ones in my code, and if I comment out the attribute on my test, it doesn't occur.

Comment: So it's a test assembly? It's indeed supposed to run during build then :)

Comment: I'm guessing the attribute's *constructor* is being called when the code is *loaded* in a running application, right? Not actually while the project is *building*?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, the attribute is used in a test project, which is scheduled to run during build. Therefore, the code is indeed loaded in a running application after compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual method is to use the attribute strictly as a marker. You configure it in the constructor, but take no actions. Then, at runtime, you inspect the methods via reflection, extract the configuration information from the attribute, and take the appropriate actions based on that information.

For example, if you wanted an attribute that checked parameters for null prior to executing the method, you could create it like so:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class CheckArgumentsNullAttribute : Attribute
{
    public CheckArgumentsNullAttribute() { }
}
```

Then, mark your method as such:

```
[CheckArgumentsNull]
public Foo(object o) { Console.WriteLine(o.ToString()); }
```

Then, in your code, get the `Foo` method via reflection, and check it for the attribute:

```
MethodInfo m = typeof(FooClass).GetMethod("Foo");
if (m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CheckArgumentsNullAttribute), false).Length > 0)
{
    // Check parameters for null here
}
```

**Update**: Since you need this in a scenario where MSTest is running the method, you should take a look at [this article](http://callumhibbert.blogspot.com/2008/01/extending-mstest.html), which discusses how to hook into the testing process. Basically, you need to extended from `ContextBoundObject`, and intercept the method calls to perform the attribute processing you want.

**Update 2**: Given what the attribute does, I would probably just make the environment setup a method, and call it from the beginning of the appropriate tests. I don't think you gain all that much by having an attribute. Alternatively, you could divide your fixtures by environment, and have the environment setup/teardown performed in the fixture setup/teardown. Either way is probably a lot easier than trying to make AOP work here, *especially* given the "do it once" nature of the attribute.

Comment: Yes, problem is that it's a test case which is, as a result, executed by the runner (mstest or the test agent in a lab environment). None of my code calls the attribute. Unless you know of another way?

Comment: I've posted an edit with a bit of a sample of what the code looks like if that helps at all.

Comment: The link provided was of great help. Thank you dlev. As per your second update. There are some requirements that limit my options here (wrt using a fixture setup/teardown - that's what I originally had working but it wasn't sufficient to satisfy the requirements).

Answer (score 1):

I was working on attributes, and wanted to restrict inheritance at compile time. That didn't work, however I found a solution for run-time. I kept it as compact but finished as possible, so here is the code for anybody who happens to be interested. Usage is simple: You add the attribute with the given types which are allowed to inherit from it.

The attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage (AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
sealed class RestrictedInheritabilityAttribute : Attribute
{
    public List<Type> AllowedTypes = new List<Type> ();

    public RestrictedInheritabilityAttribute (Type allowed)
    {
        AllowedTypes.Add (allowed);
    }

    public RestrictedInheritabilityAttribute (params Type[] allowed)
    {
        AllowedTypes.AddRange (allowed);
    }

    public bool CheckForException (Type primary)
    {
        foreach (Type t in AllowedTypes)
        {
            if (primary == t) return true;
        }
        throw new RestrictedInheritanceException (primary);
    }
}
```

A custom exception:

```
public class RestrictedInheritanceException : ApplicationException
{
    public RestrictedInheritanceException (Type t) : base ("The inheritance of '" + t.BaseType.FullName + "' is restricted. " + t.FullName + " may not inherit from it!" + Environment.NewLine) { }
}
```

Now, one way is to have lines of codes implemented into the constructor of the class which has the attribute, but that is not an eloquent way to solve it. What you can do instead is to run the following method early in runtime, so that you can run the checks and throw an exception (or just write a plain message).

```
void RunAttributes ()
{
    try
    {
        Type[] allTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly ().GetTypes ();

        foreach (Type t in allTypes)
        {
            Type baseType = t.BaseType;

            if (baseType != null && baseType != typeof (object))
            {
                var a = baseType.GetCustomAttribute<RestrictedInheritabilityAttribute> ();
                if (a != null) a.CheckForException (t);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
//[RestrictedInheritability (typeof (MidClass1), typeof (MidClass2))]
[RestrictedInheritability (typeof (MidClass1))]
class BaseClass { }

class MidClass1 : BaseClass { } // Is fine to go.
class MidClass2 : BaseClass { } // Will throw exception.

// These are not checked, unless you set 'Inherited = true', then you have to
// declare every single class inheriting from the 'root' which has the attribute.
class SubClass1 : MidClass1 { }
class SubClass2 : MidClass2 { }
```

When you start your program (and ideally run the RunAttributes method early), the custom exception will be thrown to indicate that a forbidden inheritance occurred. I personally might use this to prevent my colleagues to inherit from classes which are not supposed to be inherited due to being intended for low-level code which is the basis of the entire work project.

Either way this code might yield a glimpse to a working example of a not-too-simple attribute. The most I found were just attributes containing some members which then were called with barely any context.

Edit: For Unity users - look up for [UnityEditor.Callbacks.DidReloadScripts](https://answers.unity.com/questions/14709/can-i-get-a-callback-when-scripts-have-finished-co.html) attribute on a *static* method, that way you can run the script after compilation rather than run-time, which is what I personally wanted to have.