# How to write compiler instructions within C# code?

Tags: c#, .net, compilation, attributes

I've just run into [Obsolete("message", true)] attribute and noticed that the compiler actually reacts to it (i.e. doesn't let the obsolete method compile). And now I wonder if I can code such compiler-informative instructions of my own. For example, if a class is marked with [ControllingAttribute] and doesn't have a method with [NecessaryMethod] attribute, the compiler should underline that class as invalid and refuse to compile. Is it or something similar within my power?

Comment: I guess, that you'll need some kind of own roslyn analyzer

Comment: Similar post in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247834/custom-attribute-is-executed-at-compile-time

Comment: `For example if a class is marked with [ControllingAttribute] and doesn't have a method with [NecessaryMethod] attribute, compiler should underline that class as invalid and refuse to compile.` Well for that particular requirement, you could use an abstract base class where `NecessaryMethod` is `abstract`.